# Get image size in C#

Tags: c#

I want to get size of a image in C#. image is stored in `C:\images\profile\7f155d5f-4622-4e71-b376-03cba1ccd39d.jpg`. I want to get width and height of image.

so any one help me or 
what shoud I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get height and width of a image stored in your drive, you can use this code:

```
System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"C:\images\profile\7f155d5f-4622-4e71-b376-03cba1ccd39d.jpg");
MessageBox.Show("Width: " + img.Width + ", Height: " + img.Height);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
using(var image = new Bitmap(@"C:\images\profile\7f155d5f-4622-4e71-b376-03cba1ccd39d.jpg"))
{
    var height = image.Height;
    var width = image.Width;
}
```

*Edit* added @ to string to escape backslashes. Added using block

Answer (score 1):

```
Image _img=new Image();    
BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri(filePath, UriKind.Absolute));           
_img.Source = bitmap;
int _width=_img.Width
int _height=_img.Height;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Bitmap` class:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(path);

int width = bitmap.Width;
int height = bitmap.Height;
```

Don't forget to reference `System.Drawing` in your project.